# Unexpected TSC compilation behavior due to folder structure

Tags: typescript, tsc

I am breaking my head around something here. The TSC compiler is showing behavior that I cannot explain, that prevents me from organizing my code the way I want to.

**At first** a working example using the folder structure:

```
MyProject/    
    src/
      folder/
        nested-folder/
          ABC.ts
          index.ts
        index.ts
      example.ts
```

MyProject/src/folder/nested-folder/ABC.ts

```
export abstract class A {

    protected myInnerFunc(paramsObject: object): void {
        console.log(paramsObject instanceof C);
    }
}

export interface BProps {
    readonly myC?: C;
}

export interface B extends BProps {};

export class B extends A {

    constructor(props: BProps) {
        super()
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }

    myFunc(): void {
        this.myInnerFunc(this.myC)
    }

}

export interface CProps {
    readonly name: string;
}

export interface C extends CProps {};

export class C extends A{

    constructor(props: CProps) {
        super()
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }

}
```

MyProject/src/folder/nested-folder/index.ts

```
export * from './ABC';
```

MyProject/src/folder/index.ts

```
export * from './nested-folder';
```

MyProject/src/example.ts

```
import { B, C } from "./folder";

const c = new C({name: "MY_NAME"});

const user = new B({
    myC: c
});

user.myFunc();
```

Running the above output will log `true` to the console.

**Next is** a not working example using the folder structure:

```
MyProject/
    src/
      folder/
        nested-folder/
          A.ts
          B.ts
          C.ts
          index.ts
        index.ts
      example.ts
```

MyProject/src/folder/nested-folder/A.ts

```
import { C } from "./C";

export abstract class A {

    protected myInnerFunc(paramsObject: object): void {
        console.log(paramsObject instanceof C);
    }
}
```

MyProject/src/folder/nested-folder/B.ts

```
import { A } from "./A"; import { C } from "./C";

export interface BProps {
    readonly myC?: C; }

export interface B extends BProps {};

export class B extends A {

    constructor(props: BProps) {
        super()
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }

    myFunc(): void {
        this.myInnerFunc(this.myC)
    }

}
```

MyProject/src/folder/nested-folder/C.ts

```
import { A } from "./A";

export interface CProps {
    readonly name: string;
}

export interface C extends CProps {};

export class C extends A{

    constructor(props: CProps) {
        super()
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }

}
```

MyProject/src/folder/nested-folder/index.ts

```
export * from './A';
export * from './B';
export * from './C';
```

MyProject/src/folder/index.ts

```
export * from './nested-folder';
```

MyProject/src/example.ts

```
import { B } from "./folder/nested-folder/B";
import { C } from "./folder/nested-folder/C";

const c = new C({name: "MY_NAME"});

const user = new B({
    myC: c
});

user.myFunc();
```

Running the results in the error:

```
/<SOME_PATH>/MyProject/dist/folder/nested-folder/C.js:6
class C extends A_1.A {
                    ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/<SOME_PATH>/MyProject/dist/folder/nested-folder/C.js:6:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/<SOME_PATH>/MyProject/dist/folder/nested-folder/A.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)

Node.js v20.1.0
```

I have no idea how I can explain this compiler behavior. What is the cause of this and how would I organize my interfaces and classes in this project in a way that does not force me to put everything in one file?

Comment: This is a wild guess, but you have a circular dependency: `A.ts` imports `C` and `C.ts` imports `A`. This has caused issues for me in the past, although if that is the reason here, this is a strange error message to get for that.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I would have expected it to have errored using the first example as well if that would be the case.

Comment: This is definitely a circular deps issue. Solve the circularity to solve your issue.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler an explanation as to why it effects the second example and not the first would help. Where does it go wrong? Is it because of a linking process in the compiler that does not occure when all is in a single file? Saying it is a circular dependency issue is not an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circularity A <- C <- A.

Because of this, the compiler is not able to resolve the import of A in `C.ts` which means that A will be `undefined` when evaluated at runtime.

You don't have that issue in your 1st example because there is no `import` circularity.